# Rails how to fix table to take any url

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

In my Records index.html.erb I have a table with headings that are linked so that the table will order itself:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="records">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= sortable "firstname", "Frist Name"%></th>
      <th><%= sortable "lastname", "Last Name" %></th>
...
```

That `sortable` method refers to a helper in my application:

```
    def sortable(column, title = nil)
      title ||= column.titleize
      if sort_column == column 
        testvar = true
      end
      css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
      direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
      if testvar == true
          link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs btn-success'}
      else
          link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs'}
      end 
  end
```

The end product of those two is this code on the HTML page:

```
<th><a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/records?direction=asc&amp;sort=lastname">Last Name</a></th>
```

Moving right along...

So if I go to: http://localhost:3000/records?direction=asc&sort=firstname it works fine, but if I go to http://localhost:3000/records I get an error.

I've also installed a Search bar on the same page:

```
<%= form_tag records_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly when it searches, but if the search bar is blank and you click the search button it sends this URL: http://localhost:3000/records?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search= which throws the same error as sending http://localhost:3000/records

Here's the error I get:

[image: missing records maybe caused this issue?]

So my question is:

**How do I avoid this error? How can I go to /records or some other URL without throwing this error?**

Here's some more information that might be useful:
My Records Controller:

```
  def index
    if current_user.profile.title == "admin"
      @records = Record.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    else 
      if params[:search].blank? || params[:search] ==''
        @records = Record.where(loanofficer_id: current_user.id).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
      else
        @records = Record.search(params[:search])
      end
    end
  end
```

My Records Model:

```
  def self.search(search)
        if search
        results = where('firstname LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        if !results.blank? 
            results
        else
            results = where('lastname LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")   
            if !results.blank? 
                results
            else
                results
            end
        end
    else
        Record.all
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in all the wrong places. further down in my records controller I had forgotten about:

```
  def sort_column
    Record.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

all I had to do was replace "name" with "firstname" and that fixed it for me.